# How to stop infinite loops?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

this is my component:

```
const Inscriptions = () => {

    // get state
    const { inscriptions, loading } = useSelector( state => state.user );

    // flag
    const instances = Object.keys(inscriptions).length;
    
    // dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const getInscriptions = useCallback(
        () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() ),
        [ dispatch ]
    );
    const cancel = id => dispatch( cancelInscriptionAction(id) );
    const cancelAll = () => dispatch( cancelAllInscriptionAction() );

    useEffect( () => {
            const queryToApi = () => {
                getInscriptions();  
            };
    
            queryToApi();
    }, [ getInscriptions ]);

    if(loading) return null;
    
    // delete item
    const handleClickCancel = id => {...};

    const handleClickCancelAll = () => {...};

    return ( ... );
}
 
export default Inscriptions;
```

And here it's reducer:

```
case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
                loading: true
            };

        case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
                loading: false,
                inscriptions: action.payload
            };                                  

        case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true,
                loading: false, 
                inscriptions: []
            };
```

My problem is, I have another component with identical logic, but this component goes into infinite looping. Looking up my Redux dev Tools, I see that it perma calls "GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS" action, i don't know why it doesn't call it once, like I'm missing something happening in the background, but with the other component that doesn't happen, it loads, and once loading is false (when the SUCCESS action is finished)it loads.

I've tried a solution adding a flag bool to the reducer like so:

```
case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
                loading: true,
                flag: false
            };

        case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
                loading: false,
                flag: true,
                inscriptions: action.payload
            };                                  

        case GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true,
                loading: false, 
                flag: true,
                inscriptions: []
            };
```

And then changin my useEffect to this:

```
useEffect( () => {
        if(!loading && !flag) {
            const queryToApi = () => {
                getInscriptions();  
            };
    
            queryToApi();
        }
        
    }, [ getInscriptions, loading, flag ]);

    if(loading) return null;
```

And works perfect, but I still missing why i have to do this in this component while the other one performs well without this. If someone can take a look and enlighten me please, I'd really appreciate that thank you.

Comment: You can make it easier for answerers if you strip any parts of your code unrelated to the problem. For example, most of the HTML part is unneeded here.

Comment: It looks like even the dispatch is changing  so the useCallback is not able to stop the rerenderings --                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     const getInscriptions = useCallback(
        () => dispatch( getInscriptionsAction() ),
        [ dispatch ]
    );

Comment: @Al.G.you're right srry, gonna make an edit and get rid of unneeded data

Comment: @Zen_Web I don't really think so, because I have a similar callback in the other component but works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, the thing is I had other actions non-referent to the Inscriptions stuff, sharing the same reducer, so that was the interference. I've created an exclusive reducer for managing my inscriptions component. Seems that is the way of redux telling you to module your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when u call GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_SUCCESS action u change the state what`s connected to your component and it calls useEffect again, because dependencies changed

for fix

```js
useEffect( () => {
    if(!loading && !flag) {
        const queryToApi = () => {
            getInscriptions();  
        };

        queryToApi();
    }
}, [ getInscriptions ]);
```

Comment: The thing is that in my Redux dev Tools, i calls severly times GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS and eventually GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS_SUCCESS, but after that it stills calling GET_USER_INSCRIPTIONS.